# python encoding utf 'Miały' not equal to 'Miały'

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

H!
This problem concerns strings and encoding.
I have a file 'build_list.txt' :

```
Miały password
something not important
stuff stuff
stuff
```

and reading file.py:

```
import csv

with open('build_list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    for i, row in enumerate(spamreader):
        if i == 0:
            username = str(row[0]).strip()
            password = str(row[1]).strip()
            if username != "Miały":
                print("FAIL: {!r} != {!r}".format(
                    username.encode('utf-8'), "Miały".encode('utf-8')))
```

It prints

```
FAIL: b'\xef\xbb\xbfMia\xc5\x82y' != b'Mia\xc5\x82y'
```

why is so, and how to fix it?

I'm using pycharm, saving txt file in windows with utf-8 encoding (ANSI yields strange characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSV file has an invisible [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at its beginning, which is getting treated as part of the first record in the file.  [UTF-8-encoded text files aren't supposed to have byte order marks](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), but Windows programs have a bad habit of inserting them anyway.  You can make Python ignore the BOM by opening the file with the [utf-8-sig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig) encoding, instead of plain utf-8:

```
with open('build_list.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    # ...
```

But don't use that encoding when *writing* files, unless you have to interoperate with a program that fails to recognize files as UTF-8 without the byte order mark.

Comment: FAIL: b'\xef\xbb\xbfMa\xc5\x82y' != b'Mia\xc5\x82y'

Comment: Aha! Byte order marks strike again.  Would you please edit that into your question, while I rewrite my answer to actually answer?

Comment: hm? could you point me to solution? :>
// missing braces if (row[0] == "Miały"):

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using unicode in `Miały`,

1. `from __future__ import unicode_literals`
2. use `print(username == u'Miały')`

Have a look at [this link](https://github.com/luckydonald/pytg/blob/master/examples/bot_ping.py) and how unicode is being used.

**UPDATE:**

After testing your code I got `True` With No Error.

Comment: still yields false

Comment: I tested your code with no edit, then I got `True` without even adding unicode support, can you please confirm that you are running same code that you are pasted here?

Comment: @SadeghAlirezaie The problem is an invisible character in OP's actual text file; copying and pasting from the question will not reproduce the problem.